# Pivot DateTime fields by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, case

I have a table that contains employee 'punches' (clock ins/outs) each punch can be an 'in'(punch_type=1) or an 'out' (punch_type=2).

The table is formatted as follows:

```
    emp_num | report_date | punch_time             | punch_type
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 04:46:00.000 | 1
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 06:58:00.000 | 2
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 08:10:00.000 | 1
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 12:00:00.000 | 2
```

I am trying to get the first 'punch' (clock in) and the following 'punch' (clock out) in the same row. Then, of course, any following would be the same.

Desired output:

```
    emp_num | report_date | punch_in               | punch_out
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 04:46:00.000 | 2018-04-20 06:58:00.000
    1       | 2018-04-20  |2018-04-20 08:10:00.000 | 2018-04-20 12:00:00.000
```

Keep in mind there may be multiple punch in/out combos in one day as shown in the example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how is this related to `PIVOT`?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was thinking I may have to pivot the data to achieve the 'punch out column'

Comment: punch in and out are `punch types` exploded by `case statement` so if you show us what you have tried so we can be able to help you.. this is not hard to be honest

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question at first - my answer below should work for you please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to know which punch out time belongs to which punch in time. Answer: the nth punch out time belongs to the nth punch in time. So number your records:

```
select
  p_in.emp_num,
  p_in.report_date,
  p_in.punch_time as punch_in,
  p_out.punch_time as punch_out
from
(
  select
    emp_num,
    report_date,
    punch_time,
    row_number() over (partition by emp_num, report_date order by punch_time) as rn
  from mytable
  where punch_type = 1
) p_in
left join
(
  select
    emp_num,
    report_date,
    punch_time,
    row_number() over (partition by emp_num, report_date order by punch_time) as rn
  from mytable
  where punch_type = 2
) p_out on p_out.emp_num = p_in.emp_num
        and p_out.report_date = p_in.report_date
        and p_out.rn = p_in.rn
order by p_in.emp_num, p_in.report_date, punch_in;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select emp_num, report_date, max(case when punch_type=1 then punch_time else null end) punch_in, 
max(case when punch_type=2 then punch_time else null end) punch_out 
from (select *, row_number() over(partition by emp_num, report_date, punch_type order by emp_num, report_date, punch_time) value from yourtable )a
group by emp_num, report_date, value
```